# setInterval() in Vue makes my this-variable undefined

Tags: vue.js

Helloo, so I'm making a basic clock in Vue and for some reason with this code I get the initial time value into `bazinga`, but once it updates it states that it is undefined. I managed to "make it work" if I define `now` and other variables inside the `setInterval()` function as well, but this does not seem like a good choice. How come `this.bazinga` becomes undefined after the first iteration?

```
<template>
    <div id="clock">
        <h2>The time is now</h2>
        <p>{{ bazinga }}</p>
        
    </div>
</template>

<style>

</style>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        const now = new Date()
        const hours = now.getHours()
        const minutes = now.getMinutes()
        const seconds = now.getSeconds()
        return{
            bazinga: now
        }
    },
    created() {
         setInterval(() => {
            console.log(this.bazinga)
            this.bazinga = this.now
            console.log(this.bazinga)
        }, 1000)
    },
    destroyed() {
        clearInterval(this.now)
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `this.now` is undefined because you have not include this property in either `data` or `computed` prop, which is why `this.bazinga = this.now` will make `this.bazinga` undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your `const` variables inside the `data` property are not registered as component's data, they are just variables accessible in the `data` block.

I assume you want to get an updated `new Date()` everytime you call `this.now`?

I'd suggest something like that:

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            now: new Date();
        }
    },
    computed {
      hours: function() {
          return this.now.getHours()
      }
      minutes: function() {
          return this.now.getMinutes()
      },
      seconds: function() {
          return this.now.getSeconds()
      }
    },
    created() {
         setInterval(() => {
            this.updateNow()
        }, 1000)
    },
    updateNow() {
       this.now = new Date()
    }
    destroyed() {
        clearInterval(this.now)
    }
}
</script>
```

Every call to `updateNow()` will get a new Date, and update all the computed as well. :)

Comment: Ah okay, thank you! Why aren't the variables registered as data for my component even though they are in the data()-block? What is the difference between variables defined in the data block and component data in the data-block?

Comment: The `data` property is a function that should return an object containing all the properties you need in your component (and their initial values). From your code, you only returned an object with `bazinga` as a property, so it's the only one registered!

Comment: Apart from syntactic error you need to define the updateNow() as a method then it works

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry. I'm used to Typescript class based component so I don't need to specify the `methods` object. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

```
<template>
    <div id="clock">
        The Time is Now {{bazinga}}
    </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            hours: 0,
            minutes: 0,
            seconds: 0,
            hoursDisplay: 0,
            secondIterator: 1000,
            hourTime: 12,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$options.timer = window.setTimeout(this.updateDateTime, this.secondIterator);
    },
    destroyed() {
        window.clearTimeout(this.$options.timer);
    },
    methods: {
        updateDateTime() {
            const now = new Date();
            this.hours = now.getHours();
            this.minutes = this.zeroPad(now.getMinutes());
            this.seconds = this.zeroPad(now.getSeconds());
            this.hoursDisplay = this.hours % this.hourTime || this.hours;
            this.$options.timer = window.setTimeout(this.updateDateTime, this.secondIterator);
        },
        zeroPad: function (time) {
            return (parseInt(time, 10) >= 10 ? '' : '0') + time;
        }
    },
    computed: {
        amPm: function () {
            if (this.hours) {
                return this.hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
            }
        },
        bazinga: function () {
            if (this.amPm) {
                return [this.hoursDisplay, this.minutes, this.seconds].join(':') + ' ' + this.amPm;
            }

        },
    }
}
</script>
```

I made a clock component here, but basically you always want to use data props inside your components and access them with this.someproperty. You can also use watchers or computed properties to return them manipulated like i have done here.